# How to check if string not equals a Boolean

Tags: c#, string, boolean

Hi guys I want to check if a User input(String) not equals to a Boolean but apparently can't do that:

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace SymbolCheck
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String symbol = Console.ReadLine();
            int value;
            bool isVowel = "aeiouAEIOU".IndexOf(symbol) >= 0;

            if (int.TryParse(symbol, out value))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input is a number: " + symbol);
            }

            else if (symbol.Equals(isVowel) & symbol.Any(char.IsUpper))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input is a uppercase vowel: "+ symbol);
            }

            else if (symbol != isVowel)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input is a consonant: "+ symbol);
            }
```

....

I got a way to get around it but want to know if there is another way of doing it:

```
    else if (symbol.Equals(isVowel) & symbol.Any(char.IsLower))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input is a lowercase vowel: "+ symbol);
    }

    else if (!int.TryParse(symbol, out value) & symbol.Any(char.IsUpper))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input is a uppercase consonant: " + symbol);
    }
```

...

Comment: `isVowel.ToString();` does nothing useful if you don't assign it to a variable

Comment: Yes, true. Sorry forgot to remove it I was just experimenting at some point :)

Comment: Typo: `input` instead of `imput`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to check if both conditions are true: So use the `&&` symbol. Furtherfore your isVowel is a boolean, so use that directly (`symbol.Equals(isVowel.ToString()` does not make any sense)

```
if (isVowel) && symbol.Any(char.IsUpper))
```

The other check would be

```
if (!isVowel)
```

Comment: Thanks I got my answers